# Unable to print CCK field in template in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, cck

I'm trying to print CCK field in my node.tpl.php -file like this;

    `print $node->field_name_here[0]['view'];`

But when I navigate to that page, I can't see the contents.
Even when i use `print_r($node);` I can't see any info about the variable. Drupal only renders everything else in node.tpl.php -file.

BUT... if I stop the execution of node.tpl.php by putting `die();` anywhere after the `print_r()` or 
    `print $node->field_name_here[0]['view'];`
 the CCK field / variable renders as it should.

It's not issue with permission since I have allowed all users to see the contents of these fields. I even tried to disable and uninstall CCK field permissions -module, but still can't print CCK fields in my template properly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked the page source for your expected output? The `die();` statement should normally make no difference concerning already printed stuff, so I'd suspect that your output is on the page, but just not visible in the browser due to CSS/Markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$node = (object) $node;
$node = node_build_content($node, $teaser, $page);
$content = drupal_render($node->content);
// Allow modules to modify the fully-built node.
node_invoke_nodeapi($node, 'alter', $teaser, $page);
return $node;
```

Just pass your loaded node with above lines of code .This will return you the [view] of the node.

Answer (score 0):

check in the content type display tab. 
example.com/admin/content/node-type/{content-type}/display

There is a good chance that the display for the field you are trying to work with is set to none the checkbox of "exclude" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt it be the following?

```
 print $node->field_name_here[0]['value'];
```

instead?  (value instead of view) -  In scripts i acces them like that and it's also shown on the node's devel tab